# Magento 2 back-end table header issue

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, header, table

In my admin backend, it does not display table headers correctly, please check the attached image.

[image]

What could be the reason for this and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work. The Headers are still displayed horizontally.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have just remove pub/static frontend from root.

Run command

```
Php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove var folder from root and clear browser cache.

Check again.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work :(